# How to get blank cell value in apache POI XSSF

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an issue with an Apache POI XSSF in that it is not reading blank cell value.

I hava a class that implements DefaultHandler. In that class all non-blank cells are able to read from startElement and endElement methods.

I want to read blank cells in middle of the data cells.

Can anyone provide an example of how to do so or directions as to how to debug this?

Comment: Blank cells, or cells that have never been used? You do know that the .xlsx file format is sparse, don't you? Cells that have never been used nor styled don't get stored in it

Comment: Also, are you using the .xlsx usermodel, or are you doing low level SAX parsing yourself?

Comment: Yes Blank cells i mean Data is like this
A1 B1 C1
1     abc
am not able to read this B1 cell

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this very same problem today. I was using the XSSF event model. But XSSF wouldn't give a column element nor a value element for the blank columns. Most probably because the backing XML is that way.

The key is to check the attribute for the cell reference (you know the A1, A2, A3 that Excel uses). Attributes are passed to the `startElement()` callback method. We can then detect missing cell references. So if we got L1 for the previous column element and get N1 for the current column element, we know M1 is the blank/missing cell.

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,        Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
if (qName.equals("c")) {
    String newColRef = atts.getValue("r");
    coverColumnDistanceWithNulls(currentColRef, newColRef);
```

And `coverColumnDistanceWithNulls()` simply adds nulls for each missing cell reference between currentColRef and newColRef

```
private void coverColumnDistanceWithNulls(String fromColRefString, String toColRefString) {
    int colRefDistance = getDistance(fromColRefString, toColRefString);
    while (colRefDistance > 1) {
        logger.debug("Covering distance with null");
        rowValues.add(null);
        --colRefDistance;
    }
}

private int getDistance(String fromColRefString, String toColRefString) {
    String fromColRef = getExcelCellRef(fromColRefString);
    String toColRef = getExcelCellRef(toColRefString);
    logger.debug("fromCol: {} toCol: {}", new Object[] {fromColRefString, toColRefString});
    return excelCellReferenceOrder.get(toColRef) - excelCellReferenceOrder.get(fromColRef);
}

private String getExcelCellRef(String fromColRef) {
    if (fromColRef != null) {
        int i = 0;
        for (;i &lt; fromColRef.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(fromColRef.charAt(i))) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            return fromColRef;
        }
        else {
            return fromColRef.substring(0, i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what is this excelCellReferenceOrder object in your code ?     return excelCellReferenceOrder.get(toColRef) - excelCellReferenceOrder.get(fromColRef);   Can you please post some of its details please.I am facing the exact same problem.

Comment: Answer is not complete. Please post a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Building off Sab Than's answer:

```
private void coverColumnDistance(String fromColRefString, String toColRefString) {
    int colRefDistance = getDistance(fromColRefString, toColRefString);
    while (colRefDistance > 0) {
        c = getRow().addCell("");
        colRefDistance--;
    }
}

private int getDistance(String fromColRefString, String toColRefString) {
    String fromColRef = getExcelCellRef(fromColRefString);
    String toColRef = getExcelCellRef(toColRefString);
    int distance = 0;
    if (fromColRef == null || fromColRef.compareTo(toColRef) > 0)
        return getDistance("A", toColRefString) + 1;
    if (fromColRef != null && toColRef != null) {
        while (fromColRef.length() < toColRef.length() || fromColRef.compareTo(toColRef) < 0) {
            distance++;
            fromColRef = increment(fromColRef);
        }
    }
    return distance;
}

public String increment(String s) {
    int length = s.length();
    char c = s.charAt(length - 1);

    if(c == 'Z') {
        return length > 1 ? increment(s.substring(0, length - 1)) + 'A' : "AA";
    }

    return s.substring(0, length - 1) + ++c;
}

private String getExcelCellRef(String fromColRef) {
    if (fromColRef != null) {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < fromColRef.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(fromColRef.charAt(i))) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            return fromColRef;
        }
        else {
            return fromColRef.substring(0, i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly if you try and read a cell value that has not been assigned a value you get a NullPointerException or similar. You could surround the code that is examining the cell in a try-catch statement and then write your own code to deal with such scenario.

If my memory does not serve me correctly and tthe error thrown is not a NullPointerException then change the catch exception class to the relevant one.